# Redis as redistributed database (on top of PostgreSQL)

Tags: java, postgresql, redis

Original question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53607969/redis-as-redistributed-persistent-database-on-top-of-postgresql

I want to use Redis as redistributed database in system, that works on 10+ clusters with PostgreSQL installed on each server. PostgreSQL multi-master config is not applied because overhead with db setup appears. I want to use redis as redistributed cache with PostgreSQL as persistent layer. Each 5-10 minutes in-memory data must be persisted to Postgres db.

- Can that requirement be achieved by Redis? (used as db, not imdg)
- Can Redis be used with postgresql?
- Can I work with redis with Spring Data/JPA 2?

Its a simple question for peoples, who works with Redis more than few days)

Comment: Please avoid asking more than one question in a single post.

Comment: Why, its simple chained question.

Comment: Your second question will be "yes" if first one is so those could be fine, but your third question is unrelated to PostgreSQL and first two questions (except that they all are about Redis). If you put more than one question in a single post you are limiting yourself to getting answer from people who know answer to both. Or alternatively you could get answer in comment section to one of those and comments are meant only for clarification of question and offer limited space and formatting. Third option would be someone answering one question normally (with +1), marking your post "answered".